# getting 2 substr from one form submit

Tags: php

Hi I have a form with 2 text areas in the first text area my user will post of player names followed by player email,
in the second they will post a list of player names and points.
in the first textarea the posted report will look like this:

```
1st place:  MC_Vicky 
1st place email:  motherof2@mnvb.co.uk 
2nd place: TM7_CharrM5_ 
2nd place email:  snezhanagrozeva@gmail.com 
3rd place: devinm21 
3rd place email:   
3rd place:  poppop 
3rd place email: bobmitch1170@gmail.com
```

I am trying to break this report into 2 separate arrays ready to prepare it for my DB which has 2 columns.
I have almost worked this out but its now 4am and my brain hurts,
so far I have used this code:

```
    // split the player nics and email address's into seperate arrays
$rec = explode( PHP_EOL, $_POST['emails'] );
$rec = array_map( 'trim', $rec );
$status = array();

foreach( $rec as $rec ) {
    $Spaces = strrpos( $rec, ':' );
    $plays = trim( substr( $rec, 12, $Spaces +1 ) ); 
    $email = trim(substr( $rec, $Spaces ) );
    echo $plays . " <br />";
    //echo $email . " <br />";

// end of Emails split
```

when I view the echo of this code as it is I get both player name and email on separate lines but in 1 variable.
so if I un comment $email echo I get a double echo of the results.
can anyone see what I need to do ,
I need $plays to be an array of the player names
then $email to be an array of the email address's

Answer (score -1):

You need to echo outside your foreach loop. You also need to do foreach ($rec as $r) and not $rec as $rec. You also need to define two blank arrays, one for emails and one for plays. Then you can then use array push to push each value into their respective arrays.

```
$rec = explode( PHP_EOL, $_POST['emails'] );
$rec = array_map( 'trim', $rec );
$status = array();
$emails = array();
$plays = array();

foreach( $rec as $r ) {
    $Spaces = strrpos( $r, ':' );
    $play = trim( substr( $r, 12, $Spaces +1 ) ); 
    $email = trim(substr( $r, $Spaces ) );
    array_push($emails, $email);
    array_push($plays, $play);
}
echo $plays;
echo $emails;
```